# Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 391 of /var/www/html/includes/ajax.inc)

Tags: drush, updating

I'm having an a field set as unlimited in the options in my custom content type, whenever I'm clicking on "Add another item" the page is only loading AJAX and I'm getting this message in error log :

> Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 391 of /var/www/html/includes/ajax.inc).

Note: Though I haven't saved/updated the product there is also a message in `dblog` that node has been updated. This issues was not their previously until I updated my drupal version from  `7.22 to 7.32` using `drush`

Comment: Try $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

Comment: How did you fix it? I am facing the same problem. Please let me know if there is anything to do!

Comment: @Raj, please have a look at my answer, let me know if that helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue in my case was with the `max_input_vars` which was occurring on Windows machine.

- Go to `C:\xampp\php` (the path where you have installed your WAMP or
  XAMPP).
- Open the `php.ini`, the configuration file located there.
- Approx on line `475` there would be `max_input_vars = 1000` change that as per your need. In my case `1500` worked for me.

Note: I'm not sure increasing `max_input_vars` is a good practice, I have done that as I was having more than 10K fields in a single form. Still for those who are looking for an alternate solution in their development phase can opt this solution for time being.